# PowerShell - How do I pause between processes in a script?

Tags: powershell

I have one script file that has multiple calls of this code:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
```

Each call of the process has a different location(filepath).  I would like to pause between each of the processes for about 30 seconds or so.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the old legacy command of `timeout` followed by the seconds youd like for it to be timed out to, ex: `timeout 30`.

You can also just go with the native Powershell cmdlet of `start-sleep`, used just like timeout with a few more parameters. ex: `start-sleep 30`.

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
Timeout /T 30
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $fullExeLocation -ArgumentList $argument
```

Comment: Thanks @Abraham Zinala!